# GLSL 1.2 Geometry shader varying in vec4 is illegal?

Tags: osx-lion, glsl

I'm trying to figure out whether something is buggy in my graphics card drivers or just in my code. Is the following illegal?

```
#version 120 
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : enable
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable

varying in vec4 something; // <------- this

void main() 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < gl_VerticesIn; ++i) 
    { 

        gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[i]; 

        EmitVertex(); 
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

It's crashing on my OSX 10.7 (NVIDIA 9400m/9600m) laptop and I'm curious A) is this actually illegal in GLSL 1.2 or is it just my implemntation? Is there a flag of some kind to enable passing a vec4 to geometry shader in GLSL 1.2?

for the record: yes, I know this is waaaay easier in 1.3+ but I'm stuck with 1.2 at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inputs to the geometry shader are *arrays*, not single values. This is because the GS takes in a primitive, which can be composed of multiple vertices. Just like `gl_PositionIn` is an array, so too should your user-defined inputs.

Comment: Thanks! Over-tired and got tripped up by going from 1.5 to 1.2.